# JavaScript onmousemove show div and follow mouse

Tags: javascript, onmousemove

I have a list of customer records (tr in a table) in my app.

When the user hovers their mouse over a record (tr), I want to show a div which hovers over the other records and shows more detailed information about the record.

I want the div to then move with the mouse- i.e. if they move the mouse 20 pixels to the right so they can see a different field on the record (the tr), the now unhidden div should then move 20 pixels to the right to follow the cursor.

Is this do-able with Javascript/CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Do the visible/invisible part with the CSS property `visiblility:visible/hidden`, set `position` to `absolute` and then assign values to `top` (y-coordinate) and `left` (x-coordinate) on `mousemove` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Very possible, they're called "Tooltips" which there are probably a vast array of them out there.  Looks like there's one [here](http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create_lightweight_javascript_tooltip/) that is lightweight and does what you want.
If you're using a framework (jQuery/prototype/mootools etc), then there will most likely be plugins that will do this too.

Answer (score 0):

For a prepackaged jquery solution: http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/.

Check out the example that has tracking on.